# Laravel 5.1 steam login

Tags: php, laravel, steam

Maybe someone know why, [github invisik laravel steam auth](https://github.com/invisnik/laravel-steam-auth)
after login I was redirected to:

> mydomain.
> com/?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Flogin&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2

Someone Could tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a video Here if that helps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfHX-Hecu3k&feature=youtu.be

I had the same problem Here is the fix

Make Sure your **config/steam-auth.php** Looks like this with the redirect_url as /login

```php
<?php

return [

    /*
     * Redirect url after login
     */
    'redirect_url' => '/login',
    /*
     *  Api Key (http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey)
     */
    'api_key' => 'Your_API_KEY'

];
```

Also if you want it to save to the database under your users table add these to your **Create_User_table Migration**. You don't have to have the name and stuff just make sure you have **'nickname' 'avatar' 'steamid'**

```html
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nickname');
            $table->string('avatar');
            $table->string('steamid')->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

You will also need to go to Auth directory in controllers and and go into the **AuthController.php** and add these lines where it says "**protected function create(array $data)**"

```html
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'nickname' => $data['nickname'],
            'steamid' => $data['steamid'],
            'avatar' => $data['avatar'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Will also have to edit **User.php** which can be found in the App Directory.
You will need to add 'username' 'avatar' 'steamid' to **"protected $fillable"**

```html
     /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'username', 'avatar', 'steamid', 'password'];
```

Comment: What version of Laravel did you make this for?

It seems like a lot have changed in the recent 5.3

Comment: @CasperO it was for laravel 4.3 i think. I will work on updating it for Laravel 5+